# Ctrl+Alt+F1(F2,F3,F4...) doesn't work after /run was filled up

Tags: kali-linux, console

```
# uname -a
Linux kali 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2
                                              (2015-06-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# uptime
 19:31:04 up 40 days,  4:38, 56 users,  load average: 6,52, 5,55, 6,08
```

Two days ago I've lost my internet connection. Two hours I've spent for solution and found that `atop`, which was started 40 days ago, had filled up `/run`, that is why `xl2tpd` ( My VPN client ) simply could not create pid-file. I've flushed `atop`'s data and now:

```
# mount | grep run
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3284232k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1642116k,mode=700)

# df -h | grep -i run
tmpfs              3,2G         323M  2,9G           11% /run
tmpfs              5,0M            0  5,0M            0% /run/lock
tmpfs              1,6G          44K  1,6G            1% /run/user/0
```

I can not switch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> ( or <kbd>F2</kbd>, or <kbd>F3</kbd>, etc... ) to any `/dev/ttyX`. But I could switch before and <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> was opened by me.

Furthermore, nor `chvt 2` nor `chvt 3`, etc.... works...

Means, terminal shows vt7 with X-server and nothing changes, even no blinking or black-screen.

Seems, system goes unstable.

How to solve this trouble without `reboot`?

Update:

```
# ps -ef|grep tty
root       581     1 92 20:32 pts/3    01:33:03 /sbin/agetty tty3
root      1042  1012  6 Aug14 tty7     2-15:21:33 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -novtswitch -background none -noreset -verbose 3 -auth /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-Debian-gdm-ZmbLAV/database -seat seat0 -nolisten tcp vt7
root      1690     1  0 20:33 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty4 linux
root      2842     1  0 19:22 tty6     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty6 linux
root      5245     1  0 20:37 tty2     00:00:00 /bin/login --           
root      8508  7895  0 Aug14 pts/34   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root      8511  7895  0 Aug14 pts/32   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root      8512  7895  0 Aug14 pts/33   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root     10127  7895  0 Aug14 pts/31   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root     11362     1  0 21:21 tty5     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty5 linux
root     17314     1  0 22:06 tty1     00:00:00 /bin/login --    
root     23282     1  0 22:13 pts/81   00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
root     23614     1  0 22:13 tty3     00:00:00 /bin/login --   
root     23620 22995  0 22:13 pts/81   00:00:00 grep tty
root     29744 29319  0 Sep17 pts/61   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root     29747 29319  0 Sep17 pts/58   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root     29748 29319  0 Sep17 pts/60   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root     31344 28620  0 Sep17 pts/53   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root     31347 28620  0 Sep17 pts/51   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root     31348 28620  0 Sep17 pts/52   00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
```

Comment: Does `ps -ef|grep tty` show anything? if it doesn't try running `/sbin/getty 38400 tty1` and see if ctrl+alt+F1 works.

Comment: Have tried, no emotions. Silent.

Comment: I've repeated it with qemu: `# qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -enable-kvm -m 5G -cdrom kali-linux-2.0-amd64.iso -vga vmware`, thereafter `dd if=/dev/zero of=/run/test.zero`. Thereafter tried to `sendkey` ctrl+alt+f1 or f2. everything works. May be filled-up `/run` - is not a cause....

Comment: @YoMismo, is there way to send ctrl+alt+f1 directly to keyboard from shell? May be it is X or gnome locks sending...

Comment: I can see you're machine is virtualized, check this out http://blog.gnu-designs.com/solved-how-to-use-ctrl-alt-f1-in-vmware-with-linux-guests/.

Answer (score 1):

When switching in or out of a console where an X server is running, the X server gets to run code. This is necessary to reset the video mode on the graphics card. If the X server is buggy, it's possible that the switch will never happen because X never responds to the request.

It looks like your X server is in a buggy state, possibly due to `/run` having been full at some point (maybe all memory was full and the X server ran out of memory and didn't cope well?).

What can sometimes work is to start another X server (by logging in over the network). This has a chance of restoring the graphics card to a known state and unblocking the already-running server. No guarantees though. If that doesn't work, try killing the X server and then starting a new one; you'll lose your desktop session but you won't have to reboot. Again, this is not guaranteed to work.